# Using MKPolyLineOverlays and MKAnnotation efficiently

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am creating a map application, in which I am showing MKPolylineView(around 2000) and MKAnnotations with pin drop.

I want to make visible either set of MKPolylineViews or MKannotations at a time. I am managing it with 2 buttons, one button is to display set of MKPolylineViews and another for set of MKAnnotations. So I tried 2 methods to manage this scenario, which is following:

For MKAnnotations, I am removing it and adding it again. 
In the case of MKPolylineViews, I tried 2 ways:

- I tried to make all MKPolylineViews hidden to YES and NO to manage it visibility based on button click. In this case, when I make the MKPolylineViews visible from it's hidden state, not all the MKPolylineView are visible. I tried with alpha and hidden property. In both the cases, the result was same, not all the lines are visible. Is there any mechanism to make all the lines visible. Because the performance is good in this case.
- Then I tried another way, in which I removed all the MKPolylineOverlays and add it again. This case, everything works well. But the main thread freeze the UI for some seconds. Remember I am adding around 2000 MKPolyLineView. How can I manage it.

Instead of removing the overlay, when I used the hidden and alpha property, the performance was good. But half of the lines are not visible, when I make it visible from it's hidden state. Around half of the overlays couldn't be visible.

Another help that I need is since I am using around 2000 MKOverlays, the app got free for a few seconds while zooming. I think in this case, the map is re rendering the overlay at each zoom level. Is there any way to handle it efficiently?

Can anyone help me the best way to handle this scenario.

Thanks and regards,
Sreelash